# How do I use a custom attribute as the final price of a product?

Tags: attributes, price

I created 2 attributes: `sale` (yes/no) and `sale_price`

I would like to be able to determine whether `sale` is set to `yes`, then use the `sale_price` as the final price of the product, "overriding" the regular price, special price, tier prices, and if possible Catalog Price rules too.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the price used for all further calculations in the cart etc is `getFinalPrice` in the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` class. So my best guess is modifying that method. If that also overwrites the catalog price rules I don't know to be honest.

But I guess this will take some trial and error to check if everything is overwritten and it will also depend a lot on your theme. Some bought themes use `getSpecialPrice` for comparing the origional price vs any special price.